# Update already trained lstm model with user input

Tags: lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement lstm model with a smaller dataset. But it must be updated frequently with user-input everytime when users add a new data to the model or web server.

Is it possible to create updateable lstm model on the cloud server with user-input?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard. Just do your typical forward- and backward-passes with the new data.

I would suggest batching the data though instead of updating the model with every new piece.